# Binding to collection reduced to one of its properties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

i want to do sth like this:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate 
                          x:Key="BuildingTemplate"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RoomAccesses.Select(p => p.Room)}"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ZoneTemplate}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Of course the **RoomAccesses.Select(p => p.Room)** gives syntax errors, but u get the idea. I want all the rooms in the roomaccesses-object to be bound here.

Do u have any ideas how to do this correctly?

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something else you can do is use a `ValueConverter`, e.g. this is a simple property selection converter:

```
public class SelectConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is IEnumerable)) throw new Exception("Input is not enumerable");
        IEnumerable input = ((IEnumerable)value);
        var propertyName = parameter as string;
        PropertyInfo propInfo = null;
        List<object> list = new List<object>();
        foreach (var item in input)
        {
            if (propInfo == null)
            {
                propInfo = item.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
                if (propInfo == null) throw new Exception(String.Format("Property \"{0}\" not found on enumerable element type", propertyName));
            }
            list.Add(propInfo.GetValue(item, null));
        }
        return list;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

XAML use example:

```xml
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Data,
                               Converter={StaticResource SelectConverter},
                               ConverterParameter=Occupation}"/>
```

Comment: I find this awfully oversized, but in my treeview-case there seems to be no better solution... thanks a lot! :)

Comment: It is not a very good solution, e.g. it will not update on CollectionChanged and reflection might make it slow for higher item counts. In scenarios where i only need a property i would probably try to approach it via data-templating.

Answer (score 1):

What are you binding to in this example?

If you can edit the class that you're binding to, you can add a property to the class like this:

```
public IEnumberable<string> RoomsAccessed // replace string with the type of Room
{
    get { return RoomAccesses.Select(p => p.Room); }
}
```

Then update your Binding Path to just `RoomAccessed` (or whatever you want to call it)

Answer (score 1):

Expose a Rooms property in your DataContext:

```
public IEnumerable<Room> Rooms
{
    get { return RoomAccesses.Select(p => p.Room); }
}
```

and bind to `Rooms` instead of `RoomAccesses`

Answer (score 1):

Why not leaving the binding as is, like ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RoomAccesses}", and then dealing with the .Room property in the datatemplate? I mean with a PropertyPath that's easy to do.